# What houseplant is this?

Tags: identification, houseplants, palm

I'm unsure what variety of plant this is.

It's currently about 30cm tall and the most identifiable feature on it are the small hairy coconut like seeds where the shoots sprout from.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The seeds are hairy, the juvenile leaves rise each from one stem. I have never grown ginger from seed but am worried about this identification.

Comment: I'm also confused about the hairy seeds and am slightly sceptical about the identification of ginger. Ginger grows from a rhizome rather than a seed. I have dug a few millimetres down to look for the tell tale ginger rhizome but all I can see are thin roots

Comment: "Ginger grows from a rhizome rather than a seed" true but you need to know that to propagate ginger you need to split it from the rhizome and it will only have roots and a stem like a small plant would but no rhizome until it grows one with time

Comment: Many palms have hairy seeds  -- it is what's left after the thin covering/flesh of the seed is worn away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a palm, my guess is *Rhapis excelsa*, since it is a common indoor palm (house plant) which looks very similar and has hairy seed pods as well. [Here](https://www.tropicalseeds.com/rhapis-excelsa-broad-leaf-) an example of how the seeds look like. Here are some [pictures](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/New-Natural-palm-seedling-Rhapis-excelsa_62059507790.html) of these plants in the same life phase, I am not the seller, I just found them on google.

Be sure that the pot has good drainage, and remove surplus water in the outerpot. The plant is very good capable of handling shade, and doesn't need much water. But don't let the soil dry up completely either.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely palm seedlings.

No idea which palm. But I don't think it's Rhapis excelsa (lady finger palm) -- the ends of those leaves are typically square, not pointy. I've never grown them from seed, but when they put up a new shoot (they have multiple trunks), there are usually two short leaves on each frond, not one long thin one as in the photo.

More likely a pinnate palm, not a palmate palm. To me, they also don't look like Chamaedorea or Dypsis, two other common types of palms.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a [Lemon Lime Dracaena](http://www.costafarms.com/images/SlideShow/Dracaena-Popular-Houseplants-Costa-Farms.jpg)

The plant is very healthy and just the right height if it's still young

Comment: I'm not sure the leaves of the plant reflect those of a Lemon Lime Dracaena. The leaves of my plant are a solid dark green.

Comment: Hmm.. I'll think about it and check more when I can

Answer (score -2):

Ginger and it’s very very healthy also it looks like it will need repotting soon

Comment: It looks like a fat ginger

Comment: yes it does have a lot of individual plants your right they will need splitting at some point

Comment: I must admit the mulch on the pot confused me but as I have this plant growing in my cupboard it was easy to identify

Comment: I don't think the "mulch" on the pot is in fact mulch. Each hairy seed has a stem growing out of it. After digging down a few millimetres there is no ginger rhizome beneath the shoots.